# Understanding the internal structural dependencies of MVC in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm a bit confused w.r.t. the structural dependencies when designing your MVC - so we have a Model, Collection and View (I'm not using controllers as yet, but the question applies to it too). Now *who has a reference of whom* to speak in OO terms. So the collection is a list of models so we can think of it as a one to many dependency from collection to model. In some of the example codes I sometimes see some reference to a view in the 'model' object and the reference of the model in the view. Sometimes a collection in the view.

In the model I sometimes see a `this.view` and in the view I see something like `this.model.view` or a `this.model` and thus the confusion to clarify :)

So what is the 'right' set of dependencies (if there is "a" right way that is) or can everyone be dependent on everyone (don't think that is correct) I.e., who should ideally be dependent on whom in Backbone's MVC design of objects? It's just a bit confusing to know how should they be structurally related when I see such disparate examples - from a noob point of view :) As a noob what is the 'right' way to start structuring my dependencies - once I'm up the learning curve I'd probably figure it out myself, but to start with, how should one go about it? A UML-like diagram would be an added bonus ;)

Another question:
Sometimes I see two views in the same piece of code: Eg: the famous todo.js http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html

Now although I understand the need of multiple views, what is confusing is how are they different? I mean what's the difference between an 'el' and 'tagName' and how does the view behave differently if either one of them is absent? I mean in the link above one view uses 'tagName' and the other 'el' and I'm not really sure how they correlate (if at all).

I've gone through the documentation intensively, but as I said I'm still learning so I may just not understand parts of it clearly even with all the resources in place and may need some human intervention :)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Since Backbone.js is not a framework as such, there's no single "right" way to do anything. However, there are some hints in the implementation that help you to get the idea. Also, there are some general time-tested code organization practices which you can apply. But I'll explain the views first.

### Views

Views in Backbone are tied to particular DOM elements (that's what the `el` property is for).

If, when the view is initialized, it has an `el` attribute, then Backbone.js makes it a property of the new view instance. Otherwise it looks for `tagName`, `id`, and `className` attributes, creates the corresponding DOM object, and assigns it to the `el` property of the new view instance anyway. (It's explained in [the source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-119).) If there's even no `tagName`, then `<div>` element is created by default.

So, you can guess why `TodoView` and `AppView` use different approaches. The `#todoapp` element exists initially on the page in the HTML, so `AppView` can just use it. But when a view for a todo item is created, there's no DOM element for it yet; so the developer has `tagName` defined on the class for Backbone to create a list item automatically. (It wouldn't be hard to do by hand in the `initialize()` method, but Backbone saves some time by doing it for you.)

Usually a view falls into one of two categories: views for model instances, and views for collections. Backbone doesn't *force* it, but it *suggests* that it's probably what you want: if you instantiate the view with `collection` or `model` options, they become properties of the newly created view instance, so you can access them via `view.collection` or `view.model`. (If you, for example, instantiate the view with `foo` option, it will be put into `view.options.foo`.)

### Dependencies

#### Good practices

This is just my opinion.

- Less dependency is better.
- Following the MVC pattern has a lot of advantages.

  Note that Backbone.js terminology does not match MVC's classical one. That's normal, MVC != a set of classes, and its definitions vary a bit. It's more of ‘an ideal that you should have in the back of your mind’ (quoted from [What is MVC and what are the advantages of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685/what-is-mvc-and-what-are-the-advantages-of-it)).

```
MVC        | Backbone.js                 | What it does
Controller | View (mostly)               | Handles user interaction
View       | template rendered by a view | Displays the data
Model      | Model & Collection          | Represents the data, handles data access
```

- The model layer should not normally depend on anything. In MVC, model is where you access your data. That has nothing to do with, say, the presentation of this data.

  In Backbone, a model can be a part of some collection, but that's not a heavy dependency (AFAIK, it just helps to automatically figure out URLs of API endpoints corresponding to this model.)
- In Backbone, a collection may have a corresponding model class assigned, but that's also not necessary.
- In Backbone, a router usually depends on higher-level views (like views for entire pages or sections of the page), to render them in response to a change in application's state. These views, in turn, depend on some lower-level views, like widgets / page sections. These views can depend on collections and other, even more low-level views. These, in turn, can depend on particular model instances.

As an example (arrows denote "depends on" type of relationship):

```
           +-------------+              +---------------+   +------------+
State      |MainRouter   |       Data:  |ItemCollection |   |ItemModel   |
Control:   |-------------|              |---------------|   |------------|
           |             |              |/api/items     +-->|/api/items/*|
           |             |              |               |   |            |
           |             |              |               |   |            |
           +---+-+-------+              +---------------+   +------------+
               | +----------------+                  ^              ^
               v                  v                  |              |
           +-------------+   +-------------+         |              |
Page-level |AboutView    |   |AppView      |         |              |
views:     |-------------|   |-------------|         |              |
           | section     |   | section     |         |              |
           | role="main" |   | role="main" |         |              |
           +--+-+--------+   +--+-+-+------+         |              |
              | +---------------|-|-|----+           |              |
              |      +----------+ | +----|---------+ |              |
              v      v            v      v         v |              |
           +--------------+   +--------------+   +---+-----------+  |
Widget     |SidebarView   |   |HeaderView    |   |ItemListView   |  |
views:     |--------------|   |--------------|   |---------------|  |
           | aside        |   | header       |   | ul            |  |
           |              |   |              |   |               |  |
           |              |   |              |   |               |  |
           +--------------+   +--------------+   +-----------+---+  |
                                                             |      |
                                                             v      |
                                                           +--------+---+
                                                           |ItemAsLiView|
                                                           |------------|
                                                           | li         |
                                                           |            |
                                                           +------------+
```

Note that you can have multiple routers set up, in which case things may look a bit differently.

#### todos.js

In the Todos example, the developer decided that `Todo` model instances should depend on corresponding TodoView instances. When `TodoView` is instantiated, it creates on the corresponding model instance a property `view` and assigns itself to it. So that it could be accessed by `some_todo_model.view`. However, it should be noted that `model.view` is only used once—in `Todo` model's `clear()` method, to remove the view instance when the model is cleared.

I think *that* particular dependency isn't necessary. However, for such a small application, it may be okay.

I couldn't find any example of accessing `this.model.view` in the view, so I can't comment on this.

### See also

- [Answers by Julien Guimont](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477245/julien)—almost all of them are about Backbone.js, I think it's a great source of information.

Comment: +100 if I could - keep adding zeroes!!! Godliness evident in the answer :) Thankssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss :)

Comment: @Anton: `this.model.view` can be found in the initialize method of `TodoView` --> `initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'close');
      this.model.bind('change', this.render);
      this.model.view = this;
    }`

Comment: Great answer. Also, `this.model.view` should not be used as model should not depend or have access to the view (`model.trigger('evName')` & `view.model.bind('evName', view.function)` should do the trick)

Comment: @Nupul, yes, that's where a new view assigns itself to a model. I meant I couldn't find any examples of actually _accessing_ view through model in the view code. Which would be a weird thing to do anyway. Never mind.

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff Is there an online app or some tools to draw this arrow diagram?

Comment: @Anton, this is a fantastic response.